# magento - retrieve all children categories given a category id

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

As said in the title, i'm trying to do this stuff through my custom function:

```
public function retrieveAllChilds($id = null, $childs = null){

        $childIdsArray = is_null($childs) ? array() : $childs;
        $category = is_null($id) ? $this->getCurrentCategory() : $this->getCategoryFromId($id);
        if (count($this->getChildrenCategories($id)) > 0) {
            $c = count($this->getChildrenCategories($id));
            $tmp_array = array();
            foreach ($this->getChildrenCategories($id) as $category) {
                array_push($tmp_array, $category->getId());             
            }
            $childIdsArray = array_merge($childIdsArray, $tmp_array);
            foreach ($this->getChildrenCategories($id) as $category){
                $this->retrieveAllChilds($category->getId(), $childIdsArray);
            }
        }
        else{
            return array_unique($childIdsArray);
        }

        return array_unique($childIdsArray);
}
```

but seems that there's something wrong in the stop or in the exit condition. the function retrieve correctly first 16 elements. anybody could help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the class [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Category`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Category.html) already includes the function you are searching. It is called [`getChildren`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Category.html#getChildren):

```
public function retrieveAllChilds($id = null, $childs = null) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
    return $category->getChildren();
}
```

The function [`getChildren`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Category.html#getChildren) returns children IDs comma-separated, [`getChildrenCategories`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Category.html#getChildrenCategories) returns an array of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` instances.

If you want to get the children categories recursively, you can use:

```
public function retrieveAllChilds($id = null, $childs = null) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
    return $category->getResource()->getChildren($category, true);
}
```

Comment: You are exactly right, except that by default it will not fetch them recursively (so top level only). He will want to use: $category->getResource()->getChildren($category, true);